# How does Apple Mail (macOS Sierra) access Gmail?

Tags: gmail, imap, apple-mail, macos-sierra

Ever since Apple Mail gained the ability to add "Google" mail account types, it has become a lot easier to access a Gmail address from a Mac. My question is how does it do it? I assumed it used IMAP like most mail accounts, however, looking at the settings for my GMail account, IMAP access is turned off?

I tried installing a different mail client and using the Gmail IMAP settings and sure enough - can't log in because IMAP is disabled.

How is Apple Mail able to access my Gmail over IMAP without IMAP enabled on my GMail account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple Mail still uses IMAP and SMTP to fetch/send messages Gmail, **not** the Gmail RESTful API. In Mail preferences > Accounts, "IMAP" will be listed under the Gmail account.

The reason IMAP can be used even when disabled in Gmail settings is by using an OAuth token rather than a saved password. Google says this approach is "more secure" and [requires the user's permission before allowing access using a saved password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&authuser=1). The ability for macOS to request these tokens is what has been added in recent versions (e.g. Sierra); it knows to pull up a web-like form provided by Google for logging in to Gmail and obtaining a token:

[image: Screenshot of Google web-based signin prompt in Mail preferences]

This means "OS X" will be [listed as an authenticated app](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/permissions) rather than simply "IMAP" under recent account activity (found by clicking "Details" on the lower right corner of Gmail in a browser). This also means that by removing permissions for "OS X", Apple Mail will no longer have access.

Thunderbird (45.7.0) also knows to use OAuth tokens while still using IMAP+SMTP.

Comment: Also, in label settings "showing in IMAP" still have an effect on Apple Mail

Comment: So when Apple Mail is performing the AUTH LOGIN step in SMTP, the password is just the OAuth token?

Comment: @DouglasPlumley I don’t think so. According to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol), clients use the `AUTH XOAUTH2` mechanism rather than `AUTH LOGIN` with the token substituted for the password. There are some services (such as AOL) that do let the user create revocable app-specific passwords for clients to use, specifically so that clients can still use the `AUTH LOGIN` mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that they use the [Google Mail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/).  This is provided to allow programs to access GMail natively rather than using the IMAP and SMTP protocols.

Comment: They don't, at least for High Sierra.