# Download contents of Gmail to Mail.app (Mac), POP3 or IMAP

Tags: macos, gmail, apple-mail

I have a Gmail account I no longer use, the contents of which I would like to fully download to the macOS Mail.app.

How do I go about it?

I could use the standard way of adding a Google account, using the Menu bar item. 
(From [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1173079/how-does-apple-mail-macos-sierra-access-gmail) answer, I assume this uses IMAP?)
or I could set up IMAP manually, 
and I'm not sure if I can still set up POP3 manually.

The point is only to download all emails into Mail and *not* keep copies on the server.
If I set it up with IMAP, I could have it sync everything, and then drag all the mail into local folders.  However, I'm not sure if that will do the trick, given that Gmail works with labels and not folders, so will they still remain in All Mail?
If I set it up with POP3, I believe it deletes them from the server anyways, but again not sure about this.

Anyone with some background knowledge on what happens beind the scenes here in each of these cases could help me decide which is best?

Oh, and one more thing:  In each of these scenarios (POP3 and IMAP) What happens to mail that has two or more gmail labels. Will it get duplicated to each of the respective folders in the Mail.app?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Does [this article](http://vishalmisra.blogspot.com/2014/04/make-apple-mail-on-mac-os-and-ios-play.html) help?

Comment: @harrymc I have come across that one -- believe me I spent over an hour googling, but all of the "how to-s" are fairly basic and none of them gives any detail on how exactly different options behave and what happens in in the background.

Comment: Gmail still has the option for POP3, although it needs to be turned on from the Settings page within Gmail. On top of that,you can automatically set it to delete from the Gmail inbox once your mail.app client has grabbed the message through POP3.

Comment: Having partial knowledge does not mean you cannot try the procedure proposed in the article, especially since no deletions are done and you can always try again differently. I think that multi-labelled mail will surely get duplicated using that procedure, but it's up to you to find a Mail.app mechanism for that.